# spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true is ignored and ConflictingBeanException is thrown

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a spring-boot application with version **2.2.0**.

I wanted to override a bean, which spring-boot provides by default. So I tried `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` in my `workflow.properties` file.

The code is same in both java files, one whose bean is provided by default and the one which I have created. The only difference is, the java file that I have created will load the resource which I provide it, instead of loading the default resource by default bean(from spring-boot).

I am loading `workflow.properties` like this in my main Application which extends `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer`:

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure( SpringApplicationBuilder application )
{
    application.application().setDefaultProperties( getProperties() );
    return application.sources( WorkflowServiceApplication.class );
}

public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // SpringApplication.run( WorkflowServiceApplication.class, args );
        new SpringApplicationBuilder( WorkflowServiceApplication.class ).properties( "spring.config.name:workflow" )
                                                                        .build()
                                                                        .run( args );
    }

static Properties getProperties()
{
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put( "spring.config.name", "workflow" );

    props.put( "spring.config.location", "../conf/" );
    return props;
}
```

But I'm still getting the same `ConflictingBeanException`

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'stencilSetResource' for bean class [org.flowable.ui.modeler.rest.app.StencilSetResource] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.myApplication.workflow.workflowservice.controllers.StencilSetResource]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:349) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:287) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:290) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:587) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

After checking in [spring-boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/), I think that by default bean definition overriding is false, but why does the overriding not work even if I set it to true in my properties file?

**Edit:**
After going through [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.12.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html), it looks like the configuration that tells `Environment` to read properties from `workflow.properties` instead of `application.properties` happens after `ApplicationContext` is refreshed. Also a couple of properties like `spring.main.*` are read and loaded to `Environment` before `ApplicationContext` refresh happens. The link suggests to load property source into `Environment` by implementing `EnvironmentPostProcessor`, so I'll try that and see how it goes.

**Edit 2:**
Okay so I tried the approach given in documentation link in above edit:

```
@Order( Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE )
public class CustomEvironmentPostProcesor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor
{
    private static final String DEFAULT_MY_FRAMEWORK_PROPERTIES = "workflowProperties";
    private static final String DEFAULT_MY_FRAMEWORK_PROPERTIES_LOCATION = "/workflow.properties";

    private PropertiesPropertySourceLoader propertySourceLoader = new PropertiesPropertySourceLoader();

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment( ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
                                        SpringApplication application )
    {
        Resource workflowProperties = new ClassPathResource( DEFAULT_MY_FRAMEWORK_PROPERTIES_LOCATION );
        List<PropertySource<?>> propertySource;
        try
        {
            propertySource = propertySourceLoader.load( DEFAULT_MY_FRAMEWORK_PROPERTIES, workflowProperties );
            if( propertySource != null )
            {
                environment.getPropertySources().addLast( propertySource.get( 0 ) );
            }
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I can see my `workflow.properties` getting loaded in `Environment` instance passed in `postProcessEnvironment` method.

But still, I get the same exception.

Comment: The property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` should be in `application.properties` (unless you have explicitly configured Spring to load properties from `workflow.properties`, in which case you should try `@Qualifier` with custom bean name to avoid conflict and ensure intended bean is auto-wired)

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond Yes, I have explicitly configured Spring to load properties from `workflow.properties` by overriding configure method of `SpringBootServletInitializer`, which returns SpringBuilder instance. I tried the `@Qualifier` annotation, it did not work. Currently, I am trying a method written in documentation, which says to implement EnvironmentPostProcessor and add property source to environment in that implementation.

Comment: Please show HOW this is being loaded. Looks like you are loading it AFTER the initializing of the application.

Comment: @M.Deinum added the code how workflow.properties is loaded

Comment: I believe the property which I want to set is loaded into Environment before application starts

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your approach of implementing a `EnvironmentPostProcessor` worked for me. I had a similar problem where I wanted to apply `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` but I could not use `application.properties` since it must be via a shared library maven dependency.

I.e.

1. I simply added:

   ```
    package com.mycompany;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor;
    import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
    import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource;

    import java.io.IOException;


    public class MyEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
        @Override
        public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
            String propertiesFilePath = "classpath:/static.properties";
            ResourcePropertySource resourcePropertySource;
            try {
                resourcePropertySource = new ResourcePropertySource(propertiesFilePath);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Resource " + propertiesFilePath + " doesn't exist");
            }
            environment.getPropertySources().addLast(resourcePropertySource);  
        }
    }
   ```
2. And made sure to configure a `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` file with:

   ```
    org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.rei.adapter.customer.rights.orchestration.kafka.CROAdapterEnvironmentPostProcessor
   ```

After building my library jar and refreshing it in the project that uses it, I no longer saw `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name ...` errors and localhost startup was successful.